# Using a custom allocator in an iOS library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I'm creating a library that will be used by multiple types of iOS apps. Part of my API allows a user to specify routines that will be used for the library's allocations. My library is implemented mostly in C++, so this has been straightforward so far.

However, I've recently been adding some user interface functionality to the library: displaying a `UIWebView` using a custom view controller. I'm not sure how to ensure that my allocators are used for these objects.

**How can I ensure that all of the Cocoa UI objects created by my library are allocated with my own functions?**

I've tried a few things including overriding `-initWithZone` and calling `CFAllocatorSetDefault` before my `-init`. None of them have worked yet; and honestly I'm still a beginner with *Objective C* and *Cocoa*, so I'd like to know what the "correct" way to do this is.

Answer (score 4):

I'm unable to find evidence of it now, but it certainly was the case that `CFAllocator`, `malloc_zone_t` and `NSZone` were all toll-free bridged. So you could just cast your allocator to an NSZone and pass it along.

I think the problem you're going to face is that NSZone was added at NextStep so as to allow a program to maintain multiple heaps, with the feeling being that it would allow programmers to keep related objects close to one another in memory — which is good for caching — and in some cases to throw away entire object graphs without walking the graph, which is obviously fast. However the former was of little benefit in practice and the latter is more likely to create problems than to be of actual benefit. So Apple has back-peddled from `NSZone`s, gradually turning the related runtime calls into no-ops and removing detailed documentation. Apple's feeling is that, at the Objective-C level, you should not only maintain only a single heap (which is a side issue from your point of view) but that they'll always know best how to maintain it.

EDIT: an alternative idea is to replace NSObject's `alloc`, that being the thing that creates memory. The Objective-C runtime is well-defined enough that we know exactly what behaviour `alloc` exhibits, so that a vanilla version might be:

```
+ (id)alloc
{
    Class *newInstance;

    // we'll use calloc to ensure we get correct initial behaviour of
    // everything equal to 0, and use the runtime's class_getInstanceSize
    // so that we're allocating the correct amount of memory irrespective
    // of whether this call has fallen through from a subclass
    newInstance = (Class *)calloc(1, class_getInstanceSize(self));

    // the thing that defines a class is that the first thing stored in
    // it is the isa pointer, which points to the metaclass. So we'll
    // set the isa pointer appropriately
    *newInstance = self;

    return (id)newInstance;
}
```

To replace NSObject's normal init, you'd probably want to define your alternative as a category method on NSObject named, say, customInit, then use `class_getClassMethod`, `class_getMethodImplementation` and `method_setImplementation` directly on `[NSObject class]` to switch it into place. See the [Object-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) for documentation on those.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 

I just tried typecasting my CFAllocator to an NSZone and invoking allocWithZone rather than alloc. My object was correctly allocated, but my allocate  wasn't called. 

I guess this is due to the backpedaling you mentioned: allocWithZone is not implemented correctly for the type of object I'm using?

Comment: Yeah, I'd guess so. If the types were incompatible you'd have expected a crash, if they were compatible you'd expect your allocator to be used, so probably the argument is just ignored. As an alternative you could try replacing NSObject's `alloc` (or indeed any other object if you prefer) — I've updated my post on that. I guess you'll probably want to look into `dealloc` too.